# i need to write a script for telnet automation .. so i wrote a program but i am unable to change the directory using telnet

Tags: python, scripting, automation, telnet

according to my code ( it takes host from command line argument)

```
    #!usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import telnetlib
    import subprocess
    import os
    import commands

    user = "test"
    password = "test"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(sys.argv[1])

    tn.read_until("login: ")
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
    pipe = os.popen("pwd","w") 
    print pipe

    pipe3 = os.popen("cd /tftpboot/")
    print pipe3
    pipe1 = os.popen("pwd","w")
    print pipe1
    tn.write("exit\n")
    print "exit"
```

here the output for pipe is "/"
and for pipe1 is also "/"
unable to change directory through this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.popen("cd ....")` affect only the subprocess. Instead use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```
os.chdir("/tftpboot")
```

Comment: i would like to know are there any other ways of passing commands ? other than os module?

Comment: @Prathyusha, There's [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) in the Python standard library.

Comment: i would like for non-os related commands subprocess.Popen dosent work?